# How to integrate platform dependent SDKs in Nativescript on the corresponding OS

Tags: javascript, ios, paypal, nativescript, braintree

I want to try integrating the Braintree SDKs into an existing NativeScript-Mobile App. Since the SDKs are only available for their native platforms, I thought about using the NS-Marshalling to execute platform-dependent the SDK on the corresponding OS.

Since I am pretty sure that it will not work that easy, I thought about two possibilities:
Implementing the modules platform dependent in the corresponding language (e.g. iOS - Objective-C/Swift) like mentioned on the Braintree sides (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v3) and integrate them platform dependend from NativeScript (I inmagine it like a module, I say use this list of objects and I receive a "payment successful" or "payment failed" response). The OS-Dependend module would then do the rest (evaluations, SDK interaction and so on).

Another approach was to marshal every single piece of code into JS modules and execute the JS-module platform dependent. What I am missing is simply the possibility to integrate the module, since I have no idea, how I should import and access the "-Library via JavaScript (I don't even think that this is possible).

What do you think about this approaches? Is it possible to do it one way or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native libraries (e.g [CocoaPods](http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods), [dynamic and static libraries for iOS](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/Use-Native-Libraries) and [*.aar and *.jar for Android](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/plugins/plugins)) in NativeScript and access them through JavaScript/TypeScript. The best approach, in my opinion, would be to create a [NativeScript plugin](http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins) and expose the needed functionality via JavaScript/TypeScript by using data conversion ([marshalling for iOS](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/marshalling/Marshalling-Overview))
 (and [here the respective article for Android](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/overview))

As recommended by Android you can also [add dependencies to a library through the gradle file](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugin-reference#includegradle-specification)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

So - to clarify this for me: The best way would to create a Plugin for me that I would call and it would pretty much differentiate between the two SDKs and do the rest for me (and basically return "worked" or "didn't work")?